# Kafka: How can I create a fat Jar of the HDFS Kafka connector?

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I've forked off of Confluent's Hdfs connector from gitHub and added custom code which includes custom library. I'm adding this library's dependency in the hdfs connector pom file but when I run the connector on a remote server, I get class not found exception for the custom library.

- I think this can be solved by creating a fat jar of the hdfs connector.
- What would the entry point for hdfs connector be which I need to specify in the pom file while creating a fat jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could create an uber jar, I would recommend just copying all extra jars into the hdfs connect directory, as mentioned [installing plugins](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#installing-plugins)

If you insist on making an uber jar, you must use the Maven Shade Plugin, which is not part of the existing POM. 
Then, make your custom code with `<scope>provided</scope>` for any HDFS Connect dependencies already included in the Connect classpath, then after you build a shaded JAR, your options are one of the following

1. add your JAR into a `plugin.path` of the latest release
2. `export CLASSPATH` to contain a path to your jar with custom code.
3. Simply copy your JAR files with their external dependencies on top of the existing `share/java/kafka-connect-hdfs` libraries